# An equivalent condition for isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vectors, inner-products, classical-mechanics

Despite the long physical introduction, I swear this is a mathematical question.
While introducing the motion of a point seen by two observers O and O' (with respective Euclidean spaces *E3* and *E3'*), my Professor of Analytical Mechanics stated that there is an isometry between the two spaces (which is a postulate of kinematics) and then claimed that the function P = f(P', t) - which expresses the position of P with respect to O as a function of its position with respect to O' - is an isometry iff it can be written as f(P') = f(W) + Q(P' - W) ∀ P' ∈ *E3'*, where W is an arbitrary point of *E3'* and Q: E3' → E3 is an orthogonal linear application which does not depend on W (E3' and E3 are the vector spaces related to *E3'* and *E3*).
The proof of the sufficient condition was made of 4 steps: Q preserves the norms, Q preserves the inner products, Q is linear and Q does not depend on W.
In particular, the end of the second step

> u′ · v′ = 1/2 [|v′ − u′|^2 − |u′|^2 − |v′|^2] = 1/2 [|v − u|^2 − |u|^2 − |v|^2] = u · v, where u = Q(u') and v = Q(v')

relies on the first step, as *|u′| = |Q(u')|* and *|v′| = |Q(v')|*, but I do not think we can say *|v′ − u′| = |Q(v') - Q(u')|* before proving linearity.
What is the reason *u' · v' = Q(u') · Q(v')* then?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough details. If this is for $$Q\text{ exists}\implies f\text{ is an isometry}$$ then $Q$ is *assumed* to be linear and orthogonal. If this is for $$f\text{ is an isometry}\implies Q\text{ exists}$$ then you haven't defined $Q$ at all in what you've written.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: $Q$ preserves the norm so $\|v'-u'\|=\|v-u\|$. If this is unclear set $x'=v'-u'$ so that $\|x'\|=\|x\|$.

Comment: My bad, for every W, Q is defined as Q(v') = f(P') - f(W), where P' is the point such that P' - W = v'

Comment: I think that there is no reason to say x = Q(v') - Q(u'), the best we can say is x = Q(v' - u'). Then it looks like linearity is applied to conclude Q(v') - Q(u') = Q(v' - u'); otherwise, the angle between v' and u' might be different from the angle between v and u. Hope I explained it well enough.